# How to limit RDLC report for one page in a PDF

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, reporting, export, rdlc

I have a RDLC report and I am displaying it on the Report Viewer Control in my front end application. I get the report perfectly and theres no problem in it.

But the problem arises when I try to export the report to a PDF (using available option - basically the inbuilt option).

I get the report in 3 pages whereas my client wants it to be in a single page. I am not able to figure out the reason for it as in my report viewer I see only one page but in a PDF there are 3 pages.  I have only four columns with no data, still they are breaking up into multiple pages. 2 columns on 1st page 2 on second page.  Not real sure what happened to the 3rd page.  Somebody recommended changing the paper size of the default printer but I didn't think is was worth trying.

Can something be done abt it so that I can control the size of the report???

Answer (score 1):

This can be a real PITA but there are several things you can do to get you there in BIDS.

1. To see what it will look like as a pdf use the "Print Layout" button on the preview mode toolbar.
2. Goto the report properties and set the orientation and paper size as you need them.
3. Remember the margins in the report properties to make your report display area smaller. I generally set these smaller than the defaults.
4. Go back to you report items and make sure they are smaller than (pagesize - margins)

This should help.

Answer (score 1):

you can try setting InteractiveHeight=0 , I know that at least works for the MHTML output, not sure about PDF, but it might lead you in the right direction